# Convert Sitecore data sources to Guid, programatically

Tags: c#, sitecore

I want to write some code so that when the author creates an item of a particular template, the data source for that item is converted to Guid.

I know that there is an option to manually do it, but I'd like it done for all items of that template when they are created:

[image]

I was thinking of doing in on the `ItemCreated` event in C#.

I did try doing it on the branch template but hat introduced another problem where for every item, it started storing the data for that page under the branch template instead - so this definitely doesn't work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need to do this? From what I remember, the "Convert data sources to GUID" script was basically a tool to convert paths from data entered in very old Sitecore versions. Sitecore has stored the datasource as guid internally for many years. I don't remember from what version, but I think this applies to at least Sitecore 7 and above.

If you still want tob build such feature, you can make a processor that hooks into the `item:saving` pipeline, check if any of the `__Renderings` or `__Final Renderings` fields are modified, parse the xml content and find any `<r>` rendering elements having a `ds` datasource attribute (note the optional namespaces). The the `ds` attribute is a path pointing to an existing item, replace it with its ID.

Comment: Hey thanks for the response - maybe I don't need to. The problem I am trying to solve is once you create components under the data folder and you change their name later or move them into a child folder, they disappear from the page. Convert Sitecore data sources to Guid retains them - so I was wondering if that could be the case for all the pages of a particular template, so that even if authors renamed the data sources later or moved them to sub-folders, the page would not be broken

Comment: Is there another/better way to do this than not have the author have to do it manually for each page?

Comment: What Sitecore version are you on? Moving/renaming components usually works just fine, but as you say, it requires the datasources to be in guid format. It sounds a bit odd that they aren't in guid format already.

Comment: I'm on xmcloud. So the author has to manually change it every time. And that's what I'm hoping to automate

Comment: Ah, it's using the local:relativePath format? Ok,. then I'd say the initial item:saving option is the valid one.